Excel change orientation of linked data
I have a data entry sheet within which my data goes down the columns, D4:d8 for example. But as my data needs to be viewed on charts in date order this leaves me needing sheets in which to organise this before it reaches my charts, within these the data goes left to right, I can't enter data into here as I would end up making mistakes due to increased complexity.
I am linking this data from another page, formula for this is, ='Sampling Sheets'!D4, this is on another sheet, when I copy across from D4:h4, the row number remains static but the column number rises. Is there any easy way to this, would save me a lot of manual entry.
Thanks in advance

You don't have time to reply whether it resolves the query or not ?

You could use one of the followings, if i have understood correctly,
Using INDIRECT() function, the following needs to fill right:
=INDIRECT("'Sampling Sheets'!D"&COLUMN(A1)+3)


Or, Using TOROW() function, the following doesn't needs to fill right, as it will spill right:
=TOROW('Sampling Sheets'!D4:D8)



